# Python script runs in Spyder but not in Command Line

Tags: command-line, python

I have a script that executes without error using Spyder. The same script results in errors when run from command prompt. I don't know why I get the errors. I spent most of yesterday trying to understand why I get the errors and I failed. So I am here.

At line 9 in my script I have

```
import numpy
import pandas
import pyodbc
```

the remainder of the code runs odbc queries, manipulates the query results and saves the manipulated query results someplace else.

My script runs without error in Spyder.

I tried to execute the script at the command prompt running as administrator using the code below (I substituted path for the "C:\Users\RAdams\AppData\ etc"):

```
C:\path\pythonw.exe C:\path\receiving3.pyw 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

After executing, "stdout.txt" is blank and "stderr.txt" contains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\receiving3.pyw", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\path\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\path\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any idea why this would run in Spyder but not in command prompt?
Should I be using something besides command prompt?
My goal is to have this run in Windows Task Scheduler - I thought having it successfully run in command prompt would be appropriate precursor.

Also:
Yesterday I re-installed miniconda. Using conda I then installed jupyter, matplotlib, numpy, openpyxl, pandas, pyodbc, scikit-learn, seaborn, and spyder into base. I have not created any environments.

Answer (score 2):

I created a .bat file with

```
c:
call C:\Users\RAdams\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Scripts\activate base
pythonw C:\Users\RAdams\blahblah\receiving3.pyw
conda deactivate
```

Using the activate.bat file in miniconda3/scripts lets me use the environment numpy was created in (which I assume is why numpy wouldn't work before).

Everything works now - yay!

Answer (score 0):

first solution is to try running it in Anaconda Prompt if you've installed Spyder through Anaconda.
If that does not work, try changing the code location(target file) by
{cd C:\path}

then run the code normally.